# Software works when run manually through the terminal but not as an Upstart service

Tags: upstart, services

I have written a software that will act as a server to an application I've made. This works perfectly when I run it from the terminal but crashes every time on a very specific action when I run it as an Upstart service. I think it crashes when it reads from a file but it's hard to know using Haskell.

This is how I run it in the terminal (when it works):

```
cd /srv/MyApp/
sudo -u appServerUser -g appServerUser ./appServer
```

And this is my Upstart .conf (placed in /etc/init/) (which crashes):

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

chdir /srv/MyApp/
setuid appServerUser
setgid appServerUser

respawn limit 5 5

exec ./appServer
```

Have I configured the Upstart incorrectly? Or why does the program behave differently when it should have the exact same privileges and is run from the same place.

I realised I was a bit incorrect about the program crashing. The program doesn't crash but the thread does.

**FOUND THE SOURCE:** After a lot of minification i realized it crashes when it's trying to read non-ASCII characters. Why it only fails when run as Upstart i beyond me, but I have found the problem and I would say it's a bug in the compiler or in Upstart.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs (they will be saved by Upstart in `/var/log/upstart`)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no errors are displayed. Only "Client disconnected" is printed by my function that handles threads crashing (see my edit).

Comment: Does your program depend on something in the environment? Maybe some external utility you call assuming your `PATH`, which a service might not share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Why is there always such simple answers to such complicated problems. I needed to put:

```
env LAN=en_US.UTF-8
```

in the .conf

Answer (score 0):

There was some problems with chdir and upstart some time ago. Generally upstart was doing some weird stuff with the processess that resulted in ./application being executed not from the directory set by chdir iirc.

Try `exec /srv/MyApp/appServer` without chdir or `exec 'cd /srv/MyApp/; ./appServer'` (there will be scope difference for working dir here, but that should not matter in your example)

Comment: This seamed promissing but unfortunately didn't work. The first method started it in the wrong directory and the second didn't even start it. I think chdir works in my case as I list all the files that's accessed without a problem.